# Fastest UInt32 to int conversion in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, int, uint32

I have a fast bit-level routine that calculates a value, and returns a UInt32.  I need to store this value in SQL Server in a 32 bit int field.  I don't want to increase the size of the field, and just want to store the "bytes" from this function the int field.

Hundreds of these records are requested at a time, so I need the fastest way to convert a UInt32 to int in a loop.  If the left-most bit is set in the UInt32, it should set the sign bit of the int (or do anything "repeatable", really, but the sign bit would probably be easiest).

In other words, I just want the 4 bytes of a UInt32 to become the 4 bytes of an 32 bit int.  I could use the BitConverter class, but I'm not sure that's the fastest way.  Would it be faster to do this with an unchecked area like this:

```
UInt32 fld = 4292515959;
unchecked {
    return (int)fld;
    // -2451337
}
```

I see the reverse question has been asked here, and was just wondering if the answer would be the same going the other way:

[Fastest way to cast int to UInt32 bitwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600871/fastest-way-to-cast-int-to-uint32-bitwise)

Comment: It's the same, you can think of C# as C with safety checks. So if you want to typecast unsigned int to int, just use type casting. But enclose it first with unchecked, signalling the compiler not to check your intent, not doing so would cause the compiler to raise you an error that the assignment is not compatible, by incompatible, it means the fidelity of value could be lost in translation (e.g. 4292515959 is not the same anymore, become negative 2451337 (they are same in the perspective of a computer scientist [xkcd 541]))

Comment: Thanks Michael.  If you hadn't made this a comment, I would have immediately voted this in as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the unchecked version (like `unchecked((int)x)`) is the fastest way, since there's no method call. I don't believe there's a faster way.

By the way, `UInt32` is just another name for `uint`... going one way is the same as going another way in terms of performance, so this is really the same as the link you posted.

---

Edit: I remember observing first-hand an instance of a benchmark where `checked` was *faster* than `unchecked` (and no, it wasn't a debug build, it was a release build with optimizations). I don't know why that happened, but in any case, don't think that you'll gain anything measurable by turning of overflow checking.

Comment: Thanks Lambert.  Just the reassurance I needed.

Answer (score 1):

`unchecked((int)x)` is required only casting consts and checked and unchecked produces the same results (if the code can compile).

For example this code

```
uint data = 4292515959;
int uncheckedData;
int checkedData;
unchecked {
    uncheckedData = (int)data;
}
checkedData = (int)data;

Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.WriteLine(uncheckedData);
Console.WriteLine(checkedData);
```

produces this output

```
4292515959
-2451337
-2451337
```

To be more concise, this code can be compiled (same result as `unchecked((int)data)`)

```
uint data = 4292515959;
checkedData = (int)data;
```

This code (note the const) can't be compiled (requires unchecked)

```
const uint data = 4292515959;
checkedData = (int)data;
```

This code can't be compiled as well (requires unchecked)

```
checkedData = (int)4292515959;
```