# How can I convert 0-65535 to Int16 equivalent -32768-32767?

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is a really simple answer but I can't figure it out.
I've been presented with a value in `UInt32` format, although it's maximum will be 65535.
It is reqiured to convert this to `Int16` format for presentation purposes so the displayed range is -32768 to 32767.

A simple `Convert.ToInt16(65535)` throws an exception that 65535 is either too large or too small for `Int16`.

Is there an inbuilt function to handle this or can someone point me to a solution for this?

EDIT: Editted again post further discussion - 65535 is not range shifted it is in fact -32768, so I'm wanting do the conversion from a UInt32 65535 to an Int16 -32768.
Thanks for all your answers so far.

Comment: Do you want to change the type without changing the bytes? There is no equivalent to `65535` represented by `Int16`, hence the conversion failure. If you explain why you want this we might be able to help more.

Comment: Obviously 65535 is too large for int16. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: The answer you've marked doesn't match the edit in your question. That makes this rather misleading. Please change the edit or mark an accurate answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to cast int to UInt32 bitwise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600871/fastest-way-to-cast-int-to-uint32-bitwise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you exactly want. You can use:

```
int i = 65535;
Int16 x = (Int16) i;
```

This maps 65535 to -1, 65534 to -2, etc

But if you want to shift your range 0-65535 to -32768 - +32767 then you can use

```
int yourvalue = 65535; // value between 0...65535
int i = yourvalue - 32768;
Int16 x = (Int16 ) i;
```

Comment: +1 Oh cool I didn't realise a straight cast in C# would re-interpret the bits :)

Comment: and `65536` -> `0` and `65537` -> `1` which is nice.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Many thanks for this and all the suggestions.

Comment: @Tony, in the edit to your question you say "I'm wanting do the conversion from a UInt32 65535 to an Int16 -32768", this answer doesen't do that. My answer does. Why did your write the edit?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm missing something but can you not just do something like this?

```
UInt32 val = 65535;
Int16 result = (Int16)(val - 32768)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be an Int32 not UInt32 ...

Comment: In the OP it says the value is a UInt32

Comment: But what is the point of doing this?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm just answering the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to re-interpret the bits as an int16 (ie 65535 -> -1)

```
UInt32  x = 65536;
Int16   y = BitConverter.ToInt16( BitConverter.GetBytes( x ), 0 );
```

Comment: and `65536` -> `0` and `65537` -> `1` which is nice.

Comment: @Jodrell: Assuming thats what you want anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in, so you need to write your own.  Here's an extension method to do it:

```
public static short ConvertToInt16(this uint source)
{
    return (short)(source - 32768);
}
```

And the opposite:

```
public static uint ConvertToUInt32(this short source)
{
    return (ushort)(source + 32768);
}
```

Comment: but a ushort can't be negative ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use too many magic numbers in your code, you can just shift the range by adding `Int16.MinValue`:

```
short displayValue = (short)(value + Int16.MinValue);
```

Note that this will overflow if your source value doesn't fit into the range you specified. So, if you want to check for that overflow you could wrap it into a [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expression (which throws an exception on overflow), or use [`Math.Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wkwtcd4.aspx) to enforce the upper limit of `65535`:

```
short displayValue = (short)(Math.Min(value, UInt16.MaxValue) + Int16.MinValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

After your edit I think you are asking for somthing like

```
static Int16 Convertor(UInt32 val)
{
    if (val > Int16.MaxValue)
    {
        var h = (val - Int16.MaxValue) * -1;
        if (h < Int16.MinValue)
        {
            throw new OverflowException();
        }

        return (Int16)h;
    }

    return (Int16)val;
}
```

---

If you compare the `byte` layout of `Int16` `-32768` and `UInt32` `65535` with a bit of code like

```
var b = BitConvertor.GetBytes(val);
Console.Write('[')
for (var i = 0; i < b.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.Write(b[i]);
    Console.Write(", ");
}

Console.Write(b[b.Length - 1]);
Console.WriteLine(']');
```

You'll get output like

> [0, 128] // for `Int16` `-32768`
>
> [255, 255, 0, 0] // for `UInt32` `65535`

I don't see any simple byte wise conversion to give the result you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
UInt32 source = ...

Int16 result = (Int16) (source > 32767 ? source - 65536 : source);
```

Comment: Your answer seems invalid. The author wants '0' to be mapped to -32768. Your answer maps 0,1,2,3,... to 0,1,2,3,.. Please read more carefully

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, I don't know where you got that idea from - from the question "I'm wanting do the conversion from a UInt32 65535 to an Int16 -32768".

Comment: WTF! That 1 hour ago I clearly saw that in the original post there was something like "UInt 65535 should be shifted to 32767, and UInt 0 to an Int16 -32768.". It was in the "EDIT" section at the bottom of the post. Now I read the post, and there's something completely different.. The poster must have changed that. Please edit your post with some whitespace, so I can remove the -1 (which is now locked due to time limit)

Comment: Exactly, please see the edits to the original post. Chagned 1 hour ago. Seems I've read the not-yet edited post, and then your added answer, and heh, due to my knowledge, it was not valid:) Please, touch your post, I'll remove the negative.